# JavaScript prompt in function not saving value

Tags: javascript

I have a div that, when tapped, calls an onclick function called door(). A prompt comes up, and when the user types into the prompt, it goes away.

I made an if statement saying: if a variable (i) is greater than 3 (which happens when the user clicks the div again after typing into the prompt) then alert what the user typed in the prompt.

My problem comes when the user re-clicks the div. the alert that pops up saying the value of the prompt says "undefined" instead of what the user entered. Why?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #mainWall{position: absolute; width: 98%; height: 98%; border: 3px solid brown; }
            #door{position: absolute; left: 49%; width: 5%; height: 10px; background: green; bottom: 1%;}
            #widthCorridor{position: absolute; width: 5%; height: 98%; left: 49%; background: red; bottom: 18px;}
            #mainCorridor{position: absolute; width: 98%; height: 5%; left: 1%; background: red; bottom: 50%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainWall"></div>
        <div id="mainCorridor"></div>
        <div id="widthCorridor"></div>
        <div id="door" onclick="door()"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i = 1;

            function door() {
                while (i == 1){
                    var door = prompt();
                    i++;
                } 
                i++
                if (i > 3) {
                    alert(door);
                }


            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step through the code.

The first time you call `door()`:

```
var i = 1;
```

was set globally, so the value of `i` will be `1` when `door` is initially called

```
function door() {
```

the variable `door` is actually declared here due to hoisting.

```
    while (i == 1){
```

at this point, the while loop is entered, because `i` has a value of `1`

```
        var door = prompt();
```

The user can enter any value, and so long as they press "ok" a string value will be returned. If they press "cancel", `null` is returned.

```
        i++;
```

The value of `i` now becomes `2`

```
    }
    i++
```

The value of `i` now becomes `3`

```
    if (i > 3) {
```

As `3` is not greater than `3`, this `if` block is skipped, and the function ends. The value of `door` which is scoped to this function is dumped for the garbage collector.

```
        alert(door);
    }
}
```

Now for the second time you call `door()`

```
function door() {
```

The variable `door` is declared here, again due to hoisting. Declaration brings with it a value of `undefined`.

```
    while (i == 1){
```

`i` retains a value of `3` because it's in global scope, so this while loop is never entered.

```
        var door = prompt();
        i++;
    }
    i++
```

The value of `i` now becomes `4`.

```
    if (i > 3) {
```

`4` is greater than `3` so the body of the `if` statement is entered.

```
        alert(door);
```

The value of the `door` variable is alerted. It was never initialized, so it retains its value of `undefined` from declaration.

```
    }
}
```

The function ends and the garbage collector collects the `door` variable again.

Comment: LOL yes! ha I totally missed that! Good example too!

Comment: So the answer is change `if (i > 3)` to `if (i > 2)`

Comment: @Aaronpd1 Mark his answer as correct and up-vote him.

Comment: I can't upvote yet because of my reputation, but I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

your prompt is saving your value fine. However you have a logical error with the while loop or in the if-statement..

The variable "i" will always be 2 since the while-loop is false when i != 1..

I suggest you move your alert to your while.
See example:

```
while (i < 4) {
             var door = prompt();
             alert(door);
             i++;
         }
```

or you can write it as this:

```
function test() {
         var i = 1;
         var prompts = [];
         while (i < 4) {
             var door = prompt();
             prompts.push(door);
             i++;
         }

         for (var x = 0; x < prompts.length; x++)
         {
             alert(prompts[x]);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a while, why not the simple if else like this https://jsfiddle.net/g3m2jftL/

```
<body>
    <div id="mainWall"></div>
    <div id="mainCorridor"></div>
    <div id="widthCorridor"></div>
    <div id="door" onclick="counter()"></div>
    <script>
        var ct = 1;
        var words;

        function counter() {
            if (ct == 1) {
                words = prompt();
                ct = ct + 1;
            } else {
                alert(words);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Mine works but zzzzBoz's answer is the correct answer.